# Magento error when creating a product programmatically

Tags: magento-1.9, product, module, admin

I am creating an admin module where the user import's a .xls file in magento, then the .xls file can be executed and the data inside has to be imported into the products table.

This is the error I get:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`magento`.`catalog_product_entity`, CONSTRAINT `FK_CAT_PRD_ENTT_ATTR_SET_ID_EAV_ATTR_SET_ATTR_SET_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`attribute_set_id`) REFERENCES `eav_attribute_set` (`attribute_set_id`) ON DE), query was: INSERT INTO `catalog_product_entity` (`entity_type_id`, `attribute_set_id`, `type_id`, `sku`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, '2016-09-30 11:43:55', '2016-09-30 11:43:55')
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`magento`.`catalog_product_entity`, CONSTRAINT `FK_CAT_PRD_ENTT_ATTR_SET_ID_EAV_ATTR_SET_ATTR_SET_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`attribute_set_id`) REFERENCES `eav_attribute_set` (`attribute_set_id`) ON DE), query was: INSERT INTO `catalog_product_entity` (`entity_type_id`, `attribute_set_id`, `type_id`, `sku`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, '2016-09-30 11:43:55', '2016-09-30 11:43:55')
```

And this is the code that creates the product in the controller:

```
foreach ($data as $value) {
                    $rand = rand(1, 9999);
                    try {
                        // $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
                        $product = new Mage_Catalog_Model_Product();
                        $product->setAttributeSetId(9)
                                 ->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
                                 ->setTypeId('simple')
                                 ->setVisibility(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH)
                                 ->setTaxClassId(2)
                                 ->setCreatedAt(strtotime('now'))
                                 ->setSku($value[0] . $rand)
                                 ->setName($value[1])
                                 ->setDescription($value[2])
                                 ->setShortDescription($value[3])
                                 ->setWeight((int) substr($value[4], 0, -1))
                                 ->setPrice((float) substr($value[5], 1))
                                 // ->setCost((float) substr($value[5], 1))
                                 ->setStockData(array(
                                    'use_config_manage_stock' => 0,
                                    'manage_stock'               => 1,
                                    'min_sale_qty'               => 1,
                                    'max_sale_qty'               => (int) substr($value[6], 0, -1),
                                    'is_in_stock'                => 1,
                                    'qty'                        => (int) substr($value[6], 0, -1)
                                 ))
                                 // ->setColor((int) substr($value[7], 0, -1))
                                 ////////////////////////////////////// CUSTOM OPTIONS FOR TYPE
                                 ////////////////////////////////////// CUSTOM OPTIONS FOR GLASS
                                 ////////////////////////////////////// CUSTOM OPTIONS FOR ALCHOL
                                 ////////////////////////////////////// CUSTOM OPTIONS FOR GRAPES
                                 ////////////////////////////////////// CUSTOM OPTIONS FOR BOTTLE FORMAT
                                 ////////////////////////////////////// CUSTOM OPTIONS FOR BOTTLE FORMAT
                                 // ->setCountryOfManufacture($value[14])
                                 // ->setNewsFromDate(strtotime('now'))
                                 // ->setNewsToDate(strtotime('now'))
                                 ->setStatus(1)
                                 ->setCategoryIds(array(2, 3))
                                 ->setWebsideIds(array(1));
                        $product->save();

                        var_dump($product);
                        die(0);
                    } catch (Exception $e) {
                        Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($e->getMessage());
                    }
                }

                $wineModel->setId($this->getRequest()->getParam('id'))
                            ->setStatus(1)
                            ->setExecuted_at(now())
                            ->save();
            }
```

Comment: Just to be sure, check your eav_attribute_set table to make sure that an attribute set with id 9 exists.

Comment: It doesn't exist, how should I insert it into the table? I don't think I have to insert it manually, am I missing something in my code?

Comment: You have to use an attribute set id which exists. The default attribute set for products is has id 4. What is the reason for using 9?

Comment: Thank you, this solved my problem. Do you want to post your comment as an answer so I can close the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to be sure, check your eav_attribute_set table to make sure that an attribute set with id 9 exists.

You have to use an attribute set id which exists. The default attribute set for products is has id 4.